# jQuery UI Autocomplete category is selecting only results in all categories

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used the jQuery UI Autocomplete demo source code for the Categories example (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) and have it working (querying a database which returns a JSON array).

I'm building a search function for an art gallery and my categories are Artists and Exhibitions. I want to show results from one or both categories. My problem is that results are only showing when the search term covers a result in both categories.

My suggestions script uses the search term to query two different database tables. I format and append the results into a single JSON array with rows for ["id"], ["value"], ["label"] and ["category"].

So for the search term CORN, the results that come back might be:

```
  { label: "Christopher Corner", category: "Artists" },
  { label: "New Pictures From Cornwall", category: "Exhibitions" },
  { label: "Cornie Collins", category: "Artists" },
```

At the moment when I type a search term, the possible results are only shown as long as a result is possible in ALL my categories, rather than what I want, which is one or more. So when I type CORN, I can see an Artist named Corner, and an Exhibition about Cornwall,  but the minute I type the E of CORNE, all the options disappear, including the Artist whose name is Corner (which I would expect to remain).

I'm new to jQuery and jQuery UI and struggling to understand where the logic would be to select a list item from any category rather than all of them.

I have edited to add my code. This is the backend suggestions file - search_suggestions.php:

```
<?php

# if the 'term' variable is not sent with the request, exit
 if (!isset($_REQUEST['term'])) {
     exit;
 }

# retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();

# connect to database, send relevant query and retrieve recordset
include 'includes/db_access.php';

$compoundFind = $fm->newCompoundFindCommand('web_Artists');

$request1 = $fm->newFindRequest('web_Artists');
$request2 = $fm->newFindRequest('web_Artists'); 

$request1->addFindCriterion('Last name', '*'.$term.'*');
$request2->addFindCriterion('First name', '*'.$term.'*');

$compoundFind->add(1, $request1);
$compoundFind->add(2, $request2);

$compoundFind->addSortRule('Last name', 1, FILEMAKER_SORT_ASCEND);

$result = $compoundFind->execute();

if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    die();
}

$records = $result->getRecords();

# loop through records compiling JSON array

foreach ($records as $record) {

    $artistID = htmlentities(stripslashes($record->getRecordID())) ;
    $artistName = htmlentities(stripslashes($record->getField('Full name'))) ;

    $a_json_row["id"] = $artistID;
    $a_json_row["value"] = $artistName;
    $a_json_row["label"] = $artistName;
    $a_json_row["category"] = "Artists";
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

$findCommand = $fm->newFindCommand('web_Exhibitions');
$findCommand->addFindCriterion('Title', '*'.$term.'*'); 
$result = $findCommand->execute();

if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    die();
}

$records = $result->getRecords();

    foreach ($records as $record) {

    $exhibitionID = htmlentities(stripslashes($record->getField('Exhibition ID'))) ;
    $exhibitionTitle = htmlentities(stripslashes($record->getField('Title'))) ;

    $a_json_row["id"] = $exhibitionID;
    $a_json_row["value"] = $exhibitionTitle;
    $a_json_row["label"] = $exhibitionTitle;
    $a_json_row["category"] = "Exhibitions";
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
?>
```

And here is the JS in my  section which sets things up:

```
    <style>
    .ui-autocomplete-category {
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: .2em .4em;
        margin: .8em 0 .2em;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
        _create: function() {
            this._super();
            this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
        },
        _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
            var that = this,
              currentCategory = "";
            $.each( items, function( index, item) {
                var li;
                if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                    ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                }
                li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
                if ( item.category ) {
                    li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#searchInput" ).catcomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source:'search_suggestions.php'
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally this is the actual input field on the page:

```
<input class="u-full-width" placeholder="Search" id="searchInput" />
```

Sorry if this is too much code!

Comment: Can you share your code for both the Javascript and server/database side portions?

Comment: @bwright I've updated the original question with all the code. Thanks for responding!